# Javascript/node and timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, datetime, time

Lets say that a user is clicking a button, and the time is , lets say 0

first thing to do with the request server sided, is to take the time again, lets say its 0 this time too, stored in a var called `currenttime` ( with `new Date().getTime()` )

Then the server is working, and things takes time, until it calls a function to store the time, and give the user some wait time.

the problem is, lets say im sending the currenttime variable to the function and saves it, and adds lets say 90 minutes ( 1 1/2 hour).

then client sided, im retrieving the time the user needs to wait.
but in this case, the result is 90 minutes ( and some exstra secs, somewhere between 15-30 secs).

How can i make sure, from sending the request to the server, that the user do not need to wait more than the 90 minutes?

the function call:

```
// after processing things this occurs
    userData.updateTimers(userid, whattotime, 5400,currenttime);
```

the 5400 is 5400 secs as in 90 min.
the currenttime is the variable for  `new Date().getTime()` retrieved first thing in the query.

acual function:

```
function updateTimers(userid,type,sec,time) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        var newtime = time + (sec * 1000);

        var updateObj = {};
        updateObj[type] = newtime;

        usertimers.update({userid: userid},{$set: updateObj}).then(function (result) {
            console.log("updated timers");
            console.log(result);
            return resolve(result);
        })
    });
}
```

again, how can i make sture its 90 mins , and not the processing time included?
i need to make a timer update accurate.

I'm using mean stack with AngularJS front end. Would it be a workaround to take the time there and bring it server sided for future Use, or is it something better I could do ?

Because whatever I do server sided and add some wait time, it will always be a few seconds more :/

Comment: So, If I understand correctly... you want to make your function `updateTimers` end in no longer than 90 mins right?

Comment: That the user do mot have to wait longer than the time I set, from the time the user actually clicks the button.

Comment: If it takes longer than those 90 mins because it hasn't finished processing or whatever, what would you answer back then, an error?

Comment: Updated with some more info now @MinusFour , but I'm not allowing the user to wait more than 90 secs from the pressed button. Whatever I do input, would always add a few exstra secs, don't know why

Comment: You don't send the time. The time is relative. The server getting the initial request should start the ticks. Your scenario is completely hackable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `watchdog` that ticks away and test against date offsets.

You can then send the date of "finished" (`new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 90)`) to the user.

```js
//Accurate timer using a watchdog

var Watchdog = (function () {
    function Watchdog(waitMilliseconds, callback) {
        if (callback === void 0) { callback = function () { }; }
        this.waitMilliseconds = waitMilliseconds;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.start = new Date().getTime();
        var self = this;
        this.interval = setInterval(function () { self.test(); }, 1);
    }
    Watchdog.prototype.test = function () {
        if (new Date().getTime() - this.start > this.waitMilliseconds) {
            console.log(new Date().getTime() - this.start);
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.callback();
        }
    };
    return Watchdog;
}());

new Watchdog(1000, function () {
    console.log("A second has passed");
});

new Watchdog(1000 * 60 * 90, function () {
    console.log("90 minutes has passed");
});
```

Comment: I did do that too, but I still get that few exstra secs :/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem you can use something like this `Promise.timeout`:

```
Promise.timeout = function(timeout, promise){
  return Promise.race([
  promise,
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function() { reject('Timed out'); }, timeout);
  })
]);
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
Promise.timeout(yourRequestFunctionWhenUserClicksButton(), 1000 * 90); //90 seconds
```

Basically, if the request lasts more than 90 seconds it will return a rejected promise, otherwise it will fulfill with the value answered from the server.